# How to update an existing JSON file by removing an entry

Tags: json, powershell

```
# helper to turn PSCustomObject into a list of key/value pairs
function Get-ObjectMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
    )
    $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
        $key = $_.Name
        [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
    }
}

$entry = [PSCustomObject]@{
    PostedDate = "04/18/2018"
    JobTitle = "King"
    Street = "Bloor"
    City = "Toronto"
    DocumentURL = "../path/to/file.pdf"
}



$path = "A:\path\to\file.json"
$entry = Get-Content $path | ConvertFrom-Json

$entry

$today = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')#Get-Date -Date -format MM/dd/yyyy
$today = [datetime]::ParseExact($today, "MM/dd/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)

foreach($date in $entry.Closing)
{
    $newdate = Get-Date $date.ToString()
    $newdate = $newdate.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
    $newdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($newdate, "MM/dd/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)

    if($today -gt $newdate)
    {
        Write-Host $date
        #remove element from the JSON list
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how I can remove an element from the JSON Object and update the **EXISTING** file.

I am using PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10

Comment: Good grief. Use the answer you already got and save over the file.

Comment: I updated my answer in the original question, maybe it helps. Unforunately this is too much code and is unreproducable because I don't know what your JSON looks like, nor do I have the sample data to play with.